# json_encode printing html block on ajax success, need advice

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am learning how to use AJAX and PHP `json_encode()`. I am returning an array using `json_encode()` as an AJAX `POST` response:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/post/post_insert_ajax/",{
        text: post_wall, type:type, entity_id:entity_id, poster_id:poster_id
    },
    function (data){
        var postObj = $.evalJSON(data);                                 
        $("ul#post_already").prepend(//something);
        $("ul#post_already li:first").slideDown("slow");
        $('#post_wall').val("");   
    });
```

i am using jquery.json.js to explode the array returned, and i wanted to display this block of html into `$("ul#post_already")`

```
<a id='"+postObj.post_id+"' href='board/?p="+postObj.post_id+"' >
    "+postObj.post_text+"
</a>
Created on: "+postObj.created_timestamp+"<a class='showCommentBox' id='"+postObj.post_id"' href='#' >Comment</a>                                               
<div id='commentContainer-"+postObj.post_id+"' class='commentContainer' style='display:none;'>
                <form class='submit_comment' id='"+postObj.post_id+"' action='#'>
                    <textarea name='text' id='commentText-"+postObj.post_id+"' class='commentText'></textarea>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post Comment' id='"postObj.post_id"' class='submit_comment' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='user_id' id='user_id' value='"+postObj.user_id+"' />
                </form>
            </div>
<ul id='comment_post"+postObj.post_id+"'></ul></li>
```

I have tried to put all of these into `.prepend()`, but it seems not to be working that way, what should I do to achieve this? Thank you very much.

UPDATE: it turn out that i missed the concatenate symbol on few of the code, so in the mean time my solution is this:

```
block = "<b>"+user_name+"</b> posted on ";
block += "<br/><a id='"+postObj.post_id+"' href='<?php echo base_url();?>board/?p="+postObj.post_id+"' >"+postObj.post_text+"</a>";
block += "<br />Created on: "+postObj.created_timestamp+"&nbsp;<a class='showCommentBox' id='"+postObj.post_id+"' href='#' >Comment</a>";
block += "<div id='commentContainer-"+postObj.post_id+"' class='commentContainer' style='display:none;'>";
block += "<form class='submit_comment' id='"+postObj.post_id+"' action='#'><textarea name='text' id='commentText-"+postObj.post_id+"' class='commentText'></textarea>";
block += "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post Comment' id='"+postObj.post_id+"' class='submit_comment' />";
block += "<input type='hidden' name='user_id' id='user_id' value='"+postObj.user_id+"' />";
block += "</form></div><ul id='comment_post"+postObj.post_id+"'></ul></li>";
```

and on success i called the HTML:

```
$("ul#post_already").prepend(HTML);
```

it works for now, but i still see this as messy lines, not a best practice, is there any workaround to do this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to use the [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method to convert a JSON array into data JavaScript can use. So, back to the answer, say we have an array like this from the server, before it is JSON encoded:

```
$array = array('one' => '1', 'two' => '2', 'three' => '3', 'four' => '4');
```

You can use jQuery to fetch the data then iterate through the data like this:

```
var HTML;
var returnedData = $.parseJSON(data);

$.each(returnedData, function(key, value) {
  HTML += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
});

$('.unorderedList').append(HTML);
```

So, that is a *basic* way to get data from the server, and attach it to a list. Of course, you can change the generated output, or even complicate the JSON array for a more fancy output.

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: great man thanks, i am gonna try this, and get back at you asap, thanks again

Comment: Not a problem, man. Hope it works well for you. Oh... and, using the above technique, you don't need the "jquery.json.js" file to explode the array. All of the functionally I demoed above is built into the jQuery core.

Comment: not exactly like what i wanted though, but i gain new knowledge because of what you pointed me up there :), anyway how can i simplify the messy codes on my update ? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can... check my post below for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is difficult to provide direct pointers without actually *seeing* how it works as a whole, you could have these elements already on the page.

```
<span class="userName" style="font-weight:bolder"></span> posted on <br />
<a class="viewer" ></a><br />
Created on: <span class="created"></span>
<!-- ... and so on //-->
```

Although I didn't include the *whole* code, it should get the point across. You can use jQuery to manipulate the code on the page. So, changing each value from the top down:

```
$('span.userName').text(user_name);
$('a.userName').attr('id', postObj.post_id);
$('span.created').text(postObj.created_timestamp);
// ... and so on
```

Depending on what you are doing, it may not work, but is the only other alternative I know of if you are trying to avoid messy looking JavaScript.

Hope that helps,
spryno724